# After the Winter Bash

Tags: feature-request, fun, winter-bash

I have decided we need a:

> Summer Party

No hats, but shades and bikinis.

Comment: Nah, it'll take away from the cozy fun and anticipation we experience *once* a year...

Comment: holiday in the Arctic, then?

Comment: Hopefully, the vamps will get crisped.

Comment: I like hats. Would look horrendous in a bikini, probably from the droopy shoulders due to extra keyboard time. Never can find shades that fit/work/look good, must be the square face and bushy beard. :b

Comment: No hats?!? Heresy. Also, you really should wear a hat in the sun to reduce the risk of skin cancer.

Comment: But then in Australia we would be having winterbash and summer party at the same time....

Comment: @angussidney; so Easter is in the Fall?

Answer (score 8):

I don't see why we need this. Of course, it will be fun (at least, most users see it that way).

Winterbash was introduced to mitigate the lower visitor counts during the winter holiday season. This idea worked out well, but only has a limited use. I don't see why we would need a Summerbash (or anything like it):

- It will push away active users who don't like the bash for the negative side effects (like users who crash into a chat room just for the hat, etc.);
- It will take away the special character of Winterbash if repeated to often.

Comment: of course, this was my hidden agenda

Comment: What exactly...?

Comment: no shades, no bikini, no party

Comment: @JonMarkPerry you are free to wear your bikini in the summer while surfing the SE network. Share some pictures when you do.

Comment: usually i don't wear anything; @rene

Comment: If that is the case then please keep the photo's private ...